# Remove margin view in scrollview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have a scrollview that will add custom views to add some information. However when I add the view in scrollview he gets a margin on the left and at the top, even though I set the axis x and y the margin continues, see in the image.
ps:I'm using Xamarin, know more objective c / cocoa

[image]

add view

```
    private NSView viewToBeAdded(float x,float y) 
    {
        NSBox nbox =  new NSBox (new RectangleF (x,y, BOX_WIDTH, BOX_HEIGHT))
        {
            BoxType = NSBoxType.NSBoxCustom,
            BorderType = NSBorderType.NoBorder,
            TitlePosition = NSTitlePosition.NoTitle,
            FillColor = NSColor.White,
            Shadow = new NSShadow () { ShadowColor = NSColor.LightGray, ShadowOffset = new System.Drawing.SizeF (1, -1.5f), ShadowBlurRadius = 1.0f},
        };
        nbox.AddSubview (Imagem());
        return nbox;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the scrollview code?

Comment: code has not simply created it on a panel, then use the ai .xib

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what you mean. Are you adding the views in Interface Builder?

Comment: not to add a new view is the code I put there